# Saving dynamically generated jqgrid columns

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid

I have a jqgrid with generated columns like this (in a ASP.NET MVC 3 project). They use inline editing :

```
@foreach (var template in Model.TemplateList.Where(m => m.Type == 2))
{
<text>
  { name: 'A'+'@template.ID', index: 'A'+'@template.ID', width: 40, align: 'left',
       editable: true, 
       editoptions: { dataEvents: [{ type: 'keyup', fn: function (e) {
       var $tr = $(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow"), rowId = $tr.attr("id");
       var nextRow = parseInt(rowId, 10) + 1;
       var total = parseInt(e.target.value, 10);
       if (isNaN(total)) {
           total = 0;
       }
       ChangeValue('A'+'@template.ID', total, $tr);
   }}]}},
 </text>
 }
```

The columns are generated and work well, until I try to save them. I'm trying to give the value to the controller, but it doesn't seem to work. I already tried to give the same name to all column to get them in an array :

```
... name: 'templateColumns', index: 'A'+'@template.ID', width: 40, align: 'left', ...
```

and in the controller :

```
public ActionResult SaveRow(string[] templateColumns)
```

but it didn't work (I only got the value of the last column)

Comment: can you tell me how you are saving the row, are you sending some ajax request or using saveRow or EditRow method?

Comment: from your code its not clear how are you saving the Rows, can you put some more code about how you are saving the rows

Comment: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:colmodel_options read this your name should be unique for all columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can not have same names for all the columns, check the link i gave u in comments. Now if you give one column name as ''A'+'@template.ID'' and lets suppose it is getting rendered like A1, A2 then in your controller you should accept something like this only.

`public ActionResult SaveRow(string A1, string A2)`

Your column name and parameters in controller should be same.